# xpath to get all the childrens text

Tags: xpath

Is there any way to get all the childrens node values within the ul tag.

Input:

```
<ul>
    <li class="type">Industry</li> 

    <li><a href="/store/Browse/?N=355+361+4294855087">Automotive</a></li>                            

    <li><a href="/store/Browse/?N=355+361+4294855065">Parts </a></li>                                

    <li>Tires</li>                  
</ul>
```

Output: Industry, Automotive, Parts, Tires.

Answer (score 38):

This will retrieve all text elements with a parent `ul` element.

```
//ul/descendant::*/text()
```

Comment: Tried this and it wouldn't work:  /a[not(contains(descendant::*/text(),'Networks'))]

Comment: More accurate answer is to use `descendant-or-self` to get the text of the element itself, if the element does not have any children.

Answer (score 27):

You can use XPath axis. An axis represents a relationship to the context node, and is used to locate nodes relative to that node on the tree. As of today there are [13 axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes). You can use `descendant` for all of the children (including nested) of the context node  or `descendant-or-self` axis which indicates the context node and all of its descendants. For example:

```
//ul/descendant::*/text()
//ul/descendant-or-self::*/text()
```