# Python element tree - extract text from element, stripping tags

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

With ElementTree in Python, how can I extract all the text from a node, stripping any tags in that element and keeping only the text?

For example, say I have the following:

```
<tag>
  Some <a>example</a> text
</tag>
```

I want to return `Some example text`. How do I go about doing this? So far, the approaches I've taken have had fairly disastrous outcomes.

Comment: IIRC [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) has some simple ways to take care of that...

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765848/remove-a-tag-using-beautifulsoup-but-keep-its-contents?rq=1)

Comment: If possible, I'd like to avoid using additional external libraries

Comment: Undoubtedly it would be incorrect (I think) because regex is bad for XML, but you *could* try something like `re.sub(r'\<.*?\>', '', text)`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are running under Python 3.2+, you can use `itertext`.

`itertext` creates a text iterator which loops over this element and all subelements, in document order, and returns all inner text:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = '<tag>Some <a>example</a> text</tag>'
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(''.join(tree.itertext()))

# -> 'Some example text'
```

If you are running in a lower version of Python, you can reuse [the implementation of `itertext()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L498) by attaching it to the `Element` class, after which you can call it exactly like above:

```
# original implementation of .itertext() for Python 2.7
def itertext(self):
    tag = self.tag
    if not isinstance(tag, basestring) and tag is not None:
        return
    if self.text:
        yield self.text
    for e in self:
        for s in e.itertext():
            yield s
        if e.tail:
            yield e.tail

# if necessary, monkey-patch the Element class
if 'itertext' not in ET.Element.__dict__:
    ET.Element.itertext = itertext

xml = '<tag>Some <a>example</a> text</tag>'
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(''.join(tree.itertext()))

# -> 'Some example text'
```

Comment: Thank you, was searching for this for a while!

Answer (score 5):

As the documentation says, if you want to read only the text, without any intermediate tags, you have to recursively concatenate all `text` and `tail` attributes in the correct order.

However, recent-enough versions (including the ones in the stdlib in 2.7 and 3.2, but not 2.6 or 3.1, and the current released versions of both `ElementTree` and `lxml` on PyPI) can do this for you automatically in the [`tostring`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) method:

```
>>> s = '''<tag>
...   Some <a>example</a> text
... </tag>'''
>>> t = ElementTree.fromstring(s)
>>> ElementTree.tostring(s, method='text')
'\n  Some example text\n'
```

If you also want to strip whitespace from the text, you'll need to do so manually. In your simple case, that's easy:

```
>>> ElementTree.tostring(s, method='text').strip()
'Some example text'
```

In more complicated cases, however, where you want to strip out whitespace within intermediate tags, you'll probably have to fall back on recursively processing the `text`s and `tail`s. That's not too hard; you just have to remember to deal with the possibility that the attributes may be `None`. For example, here's a skeleton you can hook your own code on:

```
def textify(t):
    s = []
    if t.text:
        s.append(t.text)
    for child in t.getchildren():
        s.extend(textify(child))
    if t.tail:
        s.append(t.tail)
    return ''.join(s)
```

This version only works when `text` and `tail` are guaranteed to be a `str` or `None`. For trees you build up manually, that's not guaranteed to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Aslo exists a very simple solution in case it's possible to use XPath. It's called XPath Axes: [more about it can be found here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp).

When having a node (like a tag `div`) which itself contains text and other nodes as well (like tags `a` or `center` or another `div`) with text inside or it contains just text and we want to select all text in that `div` node, it's possible to do it with folowing XPath: `current_element.xpath("descendant-or-self::*/text()").extract()`. What we will get is a list of all texts within a current element, stripping tags inside, if there are any.

What's nice about it is that no recursive function is needed, XPath takes care of all of this (using recusion itself, but for us it's as clean as it only can be).

[Here is StackOverflow question concerning this proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413649/xpath-to-get-all-the-childrens-text).

Comment: n.b.: This applies only to `lxml`. The `xml.etree` package does not know enough XPath to do this.