# python Parsing xml: get text from tag which contains <i> or <b> or similar

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using xml.etree.ElementTree. When I try to get text from AbstractText, I get None or partial text if there are formatting tags like i, b or similar tags into the text.

Here is a xml example

```
<root>  
    <AbstractText><b>1.</b>  test text <b> 2. </b> is very silly.</AbstractText>
    <AbstractText>hello <b> this is </b> another example </AbstractText>    
</root>
```

python code is

```
tree = ET.parse("xml/test.xml")
root =tree.getroot()
for node in root.findall('AbstractText'):
print(node.text)
```

and the output is

```
None
hello
```

How can I fix it? I want all the text without i, b, or other information

Comment: Read [ElementTree.Element.tail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text)

Comment: Use `itertext()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/19369901/407651

Answer (score 0):

Here a example

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('file.xml')
for node in tree.findall('AbstractText'):
    #print(node)
    print(etree.tostring(node, encoding='utf8', method='text'))
```