# Skipping "nested tags" when parsing XML with Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I currently have an XML file that I'd like to parse with Python. I'm using Python's Element Tree and it works fine except I had a question.

The file currently looks something like:

```
<Instance>
  <TextContent>
    <Sentence>Hello, my name is John and his <Thing>name</Thing> is Tom.</Sentence>
  </TextContent>
<Instance>
```

What I basically want to do is skip over the nested tags inside of the `<Sentence>` tag (i.e. `<Thing>`). One way that I've found to do that is to get the text content up until the tag, the text content of the tag, and concatenate them. The code that I'm using is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xtree = ET.parse('some_file.xml')
xroot = xtree.getroot()

for node in xroot:
    text_before = node[0][0].text
    text_nested = node[0][0][0].text
```

1. How do I get the portion of text that comes after the nested tag?
2. Better yet, is there a way that I can completely disregard the nested tag?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The portion of text (" is Tom.") that comes after the `</Thing>` end tag is the `tail` of that element. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of that. Unfortunately there are more than one nested tags, so it would also be helpful if there were a way to disregard them completely, but it seems like I'm going to have to manually write in rules.

Comment: Try `itertext()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19370075/407651

Comment: Can you edit your question to add an example with more than one nested tag - together with your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

I changed slightly your source XML file, so that *Sentence* contains **two**
child elements:

```
<Instance>
  <TextContent>
    <Sentence>Hello, my <Thing>name</Thing> is John and his <Thing>name</Thing> is Tom.</Sentence>
  </TextContent>
</Instance>
```

To find the *Sentence* element, run: `st = xroot.find('.//Sentence')`.

Then define the following generator:

```
def allTextNodes(root):
    if root.text is not None:
        yield root.text
    for child in root:
        if child.tail is not None:
            yield child.tail
```

To see the list of all direct descendant text nodes, run:

```
lst = list(allTextNodes(st))
```

The result is:

```
['Hello, my ', ' is John and his ', ' is Tom.']
```

But to get the concatenated text, as a single variable, run:

```
txt = ''.join(allTextNodes(st))
```

getting: `Hello, my  is John and his  is Tom.` (note double spaces,
"surrounding" both omitted *Thing* elements.