# python xml.etree.ElementTree remove empty tag in the middle of text

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an xml document from which I want to extract text based on tags.
The part that I want to extract text from looks something like this :

```
<BlockText attr1="blah" attr2=657 ID="Bhf76" lang="en">
Simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. It has survived not only<TIP CONTENT="­"/>\n five centuries, electronic typesetting, remaining essentially release.
</BlockText>
```

When I do

```
tree = ET.parse("myfile.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
tags = list(set([elem.tag for elem in root.iter()]))
tag = list(filter(lambda i: "BlockText" in i, tags))[0]
for text in root.iter(tag):
    texte = text.text
```

I'm only able to grab the part that comes before the empty tag `<TIP CONTENT="­"/>`
I tried to delete this tag before getting the rest of the text.
I did :

```
emptyTag = list(filter(lambda i: "TIP" in i, tags))
for e in root.iter(emptyTag) :
    root.remove(e)
```

But this is not working.
None of `<BlockText>` and `<TIP>` are direct children of root.



Thank you.

Comment: Use `itertext()`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19369901/407651

Comment: thank you! that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is what ended up working for me :

```
emptyTags = list(filter(lambda i: "TIP" in i, tags))
if emptyTags :
    emptyTag = list(filter(lambda i: "TIP" in i, emptyTags))[0]
for element in root.iter(emptyTag):
    print(element.tail)
```

But I still can't get the text as a whole block (same order). I can get all the BlockText tags and all the TIP tags but not together.

Update :
I used :

```
tree = ET.parse("myfile.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
tags = list(set([elem.tag for elem in root.iter()]))
tag = list(filter(lambda i: "BlockText" in i, tags))[0]
for text in root.iter(tag):
    texte = ''.join(text.itertext())
```

Answer (score 0):

The text After `<TIP CONTENT="­"/>` belongs to its own tail not the text of the `BlockText` tag.

`elem.text` is the text following the open tag.
`elem.tail` is the text following the close tag. Usually whitespace but in this case it's has actual text.

Comment: is there a way to get the text as a whole block because I can get each tag but it messes the order of the sentences.

Comment: From XML point of view, the text you want belongs to 2 different elements. Before deleting the child element, grab its tail text and append it to the parent's text field.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for reference only

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<BlockText attr1="blah" attr2=657 ID="Bhf76" lang="en">
Simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. It has survived not only<TIP CONTENT="­"/>\n five centuries, electronic typesetting, remaining essentially release.
</BlockText>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print (doc.select('BlockText'))
print (doc.select('BlockText>text()'))
print (doc.selects('BlockText>text()'))
```

Result:

```
{'tag': 'BlockText', 'attr1': 'blah', 'attr2': '657', 'ID': 'Bhf76', 'lang': 'en', 'html': '\nSimply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. It has survived not only<TIP CONTENT="\xad" />\n five centuries, electronic typesetting, remaining essentially release.\n'}
Simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. It has survived not only five centuries, electronic typesetting, remaining essentially release.
['Simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. It has survived not only five centuries, electronic typesetting, remaining essentially release.']
```