# Python lxml extract text when a tag exists in the middle of the text

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am trying to parse and extract all the text inside of the claim-text tag and prepare it for a csv. So each claim tag will have a column containing all the claim-text.

Basically the claims are represented in two kind of styles. The first one `claim id="CLM-00001" num="00001">` being a nested claim-text tag inside another nested claim-text tag. The second style, if you look at `<claim id="CLM-00002" num="00002">` it has a `<claim-ref` tag in the middle of the text(**which seems to be my problem**).

```
<claims id="claims">
        <claim id="CLM-00001" num="00001">
            <claim-text>1. A method of forming an amorphous metal foam formed of an amorphous metal powder comprising:
                <claim-text>mixing at least one amorphous metal powder and at least one gas-splitting propellant powder into a propellant filled amorphous metal powder mixture, such that upon decomposition of the gas-splitting propellant powder, gas-containing pores are created within the amorphous metal powder mixture;</claim-text>
                <claim-text>compacting the mixture such that the amorphous metal powder particles are bonded to one another to form a gas-tight seal around the gas-splitting propellant powder particles, the mixture being compacted at a compacting temperature and pressure sufficient to allow for bonding of the mixture, wherein the temperature is below any crystalline transition temperature of the amorphous metal powder, and for a duration not exceeding a time for any crystalline transformation of said amorphous metal powder at the compacting temperature and pressure;</claim-text>
                <claim-text>cooling the compacted mixture at a cooling rate sufficient that the amorphous metal powder mixture remains amorphous;</claim-text>
                <claim-text>expanding the compacted amorphous metal powder mixture to form a foam material, said expansion being conducted at an expansion temperature below any crystalline transition temperature of the amorphous metal powder, but sufficiently high to allow bubble expansion, at a surrounding pressure sufficient to promote expansion arising from a difference between a pressure in the gas-containing pores and the surrounding pressure, and for a duration not exceeding the time for any crystalline transformation to take place; and</claim-text>
                <claim-text>cooling the expanded foam material in order to allow the foam material to remain amorphous.</claim-text>
            </claim-text>
        </claim>
        <claim id="CLM-00002" num="00002">
            <claim-text>2. The method according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00001">claim 1</claim-ref> wherein the gas-splitting propellant powder decomposes during expansion.</claim-text>
        </claim>
        <claim id="CLM-00003" num="00003">
            <claim-text>3. The method according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00001">claim 1</claim-ref> wherein the gas-splitting propellant powder decomposes during compaction.</claim-text>
        </claim>
...
...
...
</claims>
```

I tried this: [Python element tree - extract text from element, stripping tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369901/python-element-tree-extract-text-from-element-stripping-tags)
and
this: [python xml.etree.ElementTree remove empty tag in the middle of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60321983/python-xml-etree-elementtree-remove-empty-tag-in-the-middle-of-text)

I tried the itertext() method which for the very first claim tag it gets me this(which gets me everything I need for the column):

```
['1. A method of forming an amorphous metal foam formed of an amorphous metal powder comprising:\n                ', 'mixing at least one amorphous metal powder and at least one gas-splitting propellant powder into a propellant filled amorphous metal powder mixture, such that upon decomposition of the gas-splitting propellant powder, gas-containing pores are created within the amorphous metal powder mixture;', '\n                ', 'compacting the mixture such that the amorphous metal powder particles are bonded to one another to form a gas-tight seal around the gas-splitting propellant powder particles, the mixture being compacted at a compacting temperature and pressure sufficient to allow for bonding of the mixture, wherein the temperature is below any crystalline transition temperature of the amorphous metal powder, and for a duration not exceeding a time for any crystalline transformation of said amorphous metal powder at the compacting temperature and pressure;', '\n                ', 'cooling the compacted mixture at a cooling rate sufficient that the amorphous metal powder mixture remains amorphous;', '\n                ', 'expanding the compacted amorphous metal powder mixture to form a foam material, said expansion being conducted at an expansion temperature below any crystalline transition temperature of the amorphous metal powder, but sufficiently high to allow bubble expansion, at a surrounding pressure sufficient to promote expansion arising from a difference between a pressure in the gas-containing pores and the surrounding pressure, and for a duration not exceeding the time for any crystalline transformation to take place; and', '\n                ', 'cooling the expanded foam material in order to allow the foam material to remain amorphous.', '\n            ', '\n        ']
```

Now on to the next claim tag `<claim id="CLM-00002" num="00002">` it should get me ideally:

```
The method according to wherein the gas-splitting propellant powder decomposes during expansion.
```

but it gets me:

```
['2. The method according to ', '\n        ']
```

The code I am using that gets me this result is:

```
result = []
    for doc in root.xpath('//claims/claim/claim-text'): 
        textwork = ((doc.getparent()).itertext('claim-text'))
        b=[]
        for texts in textwork:
            b.append(texts)
 
        result.append([b])
    write_all_to_csv(result, FILENAME_CLAIMS)
```

Note: The code is a shortened version. I also extract other things from the claims which work fine. Just shortened it to focus on the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the tag name from the itertext method then it will extract all the relevant text within the tag. Hope this helps.

```
from lxml import etree
root=etree.fromstring(xml)
result = []
for doc in root.xpath('//claims/claim/claim-text'): 
    textwork = (''.join((doc.getparent()).itertext()))
    #print(textwork)
    #b=[]
    #for texts in textwork:
    #    b.append(texts)

    result.append([textwork])
print(result)
#write_all_to_csv(result, FILENAME_CLAIMS)
```

[image]