# Parsing an xml file with an emphasis tag in it in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am currently writing a python script that can extract all of the text in an xml file. I am using the Element Tree library to interpret the data but I am running into this problem however when the data is structured like this...

```
<Segment StartTime="639.752" EndTime="642.270" Participant="fe016">
  But I bet it's a good <Pause/> superset of it.
</Segment>
```

When I attempt to read out the text, I get the first half of the Segment ("Alright. So what we had") before the pause tag.

What I am trying to figure out is if there is a way to ignore the tags in the data segments and print out all of the text.

Comment: There is some inconsistency in your question: the `<Segment...` text quoted does not match the text in your question.

Comment: Use `itertext()`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19369901/407651

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html = '''<Segment StartTime="639.752" EndTime="642.270" Participant="fe016">
  But I bet it's a good <Pause/> superset of it.
</Segment>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print(doc.Segment)
print(doc.Segment.text)
```

Result:

```
{'StartTime': '639.752', 'EndTime': '642.270', 'Participant': 'fe016', 'tag': 'Segment', 'html': "\n  But I bet it's a good <Pause /> superset of it.\n"}
But I bet it's a good superset of it.
```

Here are more examples. https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/blob/master/doc_examples

Answer (score 0):

```
xml = '''<Segment StartTime="639.752" EndTime="642.270" Participant="fe016">
  But I bet it's a good <Pause/> superset of it.
</Segment>'''

# solution using ETree
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
pause = root.find('./Pause')
print(root.text + pause.tail)
```