# Parsing an XML file for multiple p tags to be merged with other p tags

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an .xml file that I'm trying to extract the text from all p tags from. I've been able to implement the following code to do so, but it's not quite returning the output I want.

```
tree = ET.parse("XML_Files/Batch_1/doc1000.xml")

for answer in root.iter('answer1'):
    for p in answer.iter('p'):
        print(p.text.strip())
```

And here's the output I get from that code.

DECEMBER 12TH
PRINCIPAL MR. ROBERTSON
DEAR SIR,
I WANT TO
I SUGGEST THAT WE SHOULD GO TO THE NATIONAL ART GALLERY IN THE MORNING AND INSTEAD OF HAVING THE AFTERNOON FREE WE COULD GO TO THE FASHION AND LEISURE SHOW.
I WILL BE
YOURS FAITHFULLY

What I need though, is the text from the p tags, the text within the i tags within the NS tags, and all text still within the p tags, merged into one string.

Specifically, what I would want is the following output:

> DECEMBER 12TH PRINCIPAL MR. ROBERTSON DEAR SIR, I WANT TO THAK YOU FOR PREPARING SUCH A GOOD PROGRAMME FOR US AND ESPECIALLY FOR TAKING US TO THE RIVER TRIP TO GREENWICH. I WOULD LIKE TO KNOW IF THERE IS ANY CHANCE OF CHANGING THE PROGRAMME BECAUSE WE HAVE FOUND A VERY INTERESTING ACTIVITY TO DO ON TUESDAY 14 MARCH. IT CONSISTS ON VISITING THE LONDON FASHION AND LEISURE SHOW IN THE CENTRAL EXHIBITION HALL. I THINK IT'S A GREAT OPPORTUNITY TO MAKE GREATER USE OF OUR KNOWLEDGE OF ENGLISH LANGUAGE. ON THE OTHER HAND, WE COULD LEARN THE DIFFERENT WAYS TO GET TO THE CENTRAL EXHIBITION HALL.  I SUGGEST THAT WE SHOULD GO TO THE NATIONAL ART GALLERY IN THE MORNING AND INSTEAD OF HAVING THE AFTERNOON FREE WE COULD GO TO THE FASHION AND LEISURE SHOW. I WILL BE WRITING ANXIOUSLY FOR YOUR RESPONSE. YOURS FAITHFULLY

Any help would be appreciated, thank you! A look at .xml file is below.

```
<learner><head sortkey="TR3*0100*2000*02">
  <candidate><personnel><language>Catalan</language><age>16-20</age></personnel><score>28.00</score></candidate>
  <text>
     <answer1>
       <question_number>1</question_number>
       <exam_score>2.3</exam_score>
         <coded_answer>
          <p>DECEMBER 12TH</p>
          <p>PRINCIPAL MR. ROBERTSON</p>
          <p>DEAR SIR,</p>
          <p>I WANT TO <NS type="S"><i>THAK</i><c>THANK</c></NS> YOU FOR PREPARING SUCH A GOOD PROGRAMME FOR US AND ESPECIALLY FOR TAKING US <NS type="RT"><i>TO</i><c>ON</c></NS> THE RIVER TRIP TO GREENWICH. I WOULD LIKE TO KNOW IF THERE IS ANY CHANCE OF CHANGING THE PROGRAMME BECAUSE WE HAVE FOUND A VERY INTERESTING ACTIVITY TO DO ON TUESDAY 14 MARCH. IT <NS type="RV"><i>CONSISTS <NS type="RT"><i>ON</i><c>IN</c></NS></i><c>INVOLVES</c></NS> VISITING THE LONDON FASHION AND LEISURE SHOW <NS type="RT"><i>IN</i><c>AT</c></NS> THE CENTRAL EXHIBITION HALL. I THINK IT'S A GREAT OPPORTUNITY TO MAKE GREATER USE OF OUR KNOWLEDGE OF <NS type="MD"><c>THE</c></NS> ENGLISH LANGUAGE. <NS type="ID"><i>ON THE OTHER HAND</i><c>ALSO</c></NS>, WE COULD LEARN THE DIFFERENT WAYS TO GET TO THE CENTRAL EXHIBITION HALL.</p>
          <p>I SUGGEST THAT WE SHOULD GO TO THE NATIONAL ART GALLERY IN THE MORNING AND INSTEAD OF HAVING THE AFTERNOON FREE WE COULD GO TO THE FASHION AND LEISURE SHOW.</p>
          <p>I WILL BE <NS type="RV"><i>WRITING</i><c>WAITING</c></NS> ANXIOUSLY FOR YOUR RESPONSE.</p>
          <p>YOURS FAITHFULLY</p>
         </coded_answer>
     </answer1>
     <answer2>
       <question_number>2</question_number>
       <exam_score>5.1</exam_score>
         <coded_answer>
          <p>(FAMOUS PEOPLE, SUCH AS POLITICIANS AND FILM STARS, DESERVE TO HAVE A PRIVATE LIFE WITHOUT JOURNALISTS FOLLOWING THEM ALL THE TIME)</p>
          <p>FAMOUS PEOPLE SUCH AS SINGERS, FILM STARS, ETC<NS type="MP"><c>,</c></NS> ARE ALWAYS THE CENTRE OF ATTENTION. AS SOME OF THEM ARE CONSIDERED IDOLS, THEIR FANS WANT TO KNOW HOW THEY <NS type="RV"><i>ACT</i><c>BEHAVE</c></NS> IN THEIR PRIVATE LIVES, WITH THEIR FAMILY OR FRIENDS. AS A RESPONSE TO THIS DEMAND <NS type="RT"><i>OF</i><c>FOR</c></NS> INFORMATION, JOURNALISTS FOLLOW FAMOUS PEOPLE DAY AND NIGHT IN MANY DIFFERENT WAYS, FOR EXAMPLE, CHASING THEIR CARS, TAKING PHOTOGRAPHS OR BREAKING INTO THEIR HOUSES WHILE THEY ARE ON <NS type="FN"><i>HOLIDAYS</i><c>HOLIDAY</c></NS>.</p>
          <p>THIS SITUATION AFFECTS FAMOUS <NS type="RN"><i>PERSONAL LIVES</i><c>PEOPLE</c></NS> BECAUSE THEY ARE NOT ALLOWED TO HAVE <NS type="MQ"><c>ANY</c></NS> PRIVACY<NS type="MP"><c>.</c></NS></p>
          <p>THE MOST IMPORTANT THING IS THAT, ALTHOUGH THEY ARE FAMOUS, THEY ARE JUST NORMAL PEOPLE THAT DESERVE TO HAVE A PRIVATE LIFE WITHOUT JOURNALISTS AND FANS FOLLOWING THEM ALL THE TIME, AND ON THE OTHER HAND PEOPLE HAVE TO LEARN TO RESPECT THE <NS type="W"><i>FAMOUS <NS type="MD"><c>THE</c></NS> RIGHT</i><c>THE RIGHT OF THE FAMOUS</c></NS> TO KEEP THEIR PERSONAL LIVES <NS type="UT"><i>IN</i></NS> SECRET.</p>
          <p>IN MY OPINION FAMOUS PEOPLE ARE BEING OBLIGED TO PAY A PRICE FOR BEING FAMOUS THAT<NS type="MP"><c>,</c></NS> IN SOME <NS type="S"><i>CASS</i><c>CASES</c></NS>, COSTS MORE THAN THEY DESERVE TO PAY.</p>
         </coded_answer>
     </answer2>
  </text>
</head></learner>
```

Comment: Use `itertext()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19370075/407651

Comment: @mzjn Thank you! This is working, just need to read some more into the documentation and see if I can get it to extract text from certain tags.