# Python parse XML content of an element when there is a child element

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <data>
        <text>
            I have <num1>two</num1> apples and <num2>four</num2> mangoes
        </text>
    </data>
```

I want to parse the file and get the whole context of `text` and its children elements and assign it to variable `sentence`:

`sentence = "I have two apples and four mangoes"`

How can I do that using  Python *ElementTree*?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19370075/407651

Answer (score 1):

```
xml = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <text>
        I have <num1>two</num1> apples and <num2>four</num2> mangoes
    </text>
</data>
"""
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
x_data = ET.fromstring(xml.strip())
all_text = list(x_data.findall(".//text")[0].itertext())
print(" ".join([text.strip() for text in all_text]))
```

Iterate through the text from the parent node, and process the text as per your need

Comment: It was so helpful, thanks a lot